# Get type from javascript object

Tags: typescript

I tried to make a type from an object that comes to me from outside for further use in my code.

I am writing a hook on typescript and my i want to set up a reusable function than can return me a type like key_keyof Object[key] where values includes all possible values to this key. I get the keys of an object using keyof typeof , then get the value using these keys and then form the result I need, however I want to make this code reusable, and not copy it every time I have a new object, so I want to to pass an object and get the output type

Example:

```
const Object = {
   test: {
     '1': '';
     '2': '';
   };
   test1: {
     '3': '';
     '4': '';
   }
}

type ExpectedType = {
    'test': 'test_1' | 'test_2',
    'test1': 'test1_3' | 'test_4'
}
```

My code:

```
type Keys = keyof typeof SomeObject
type Values = { [key in Keys]: keyof typeof SomeObject[key] }
type ExpectedType = { [key in keyof Values]: `${key}_${Values[key]}` }
```

I think that this can be done using a generic or a function that returns such a type value, but I could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: Is it `SomeObject` or `Object`?  Probably you should pick `SomeObject` because shadowing the global `Object` value would lead to bizarre effects in many cases.  Looking again, could you make this a [mre] that works in an IDE and not pseudocode?  Right now it's got several errors unrelated to your question

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/ND2ljW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply so I'm notified)